# i have misconception about this loop in python

Tags: python

i have a list of items and based on it, i would like to print some pieces of information
so,a for loop over two items for example, if one on these two items found in somewhere i would like to share them the same print statement, else this, i would like to print a shared statement also, see example please:

```
book = 'long text'
a = ['im eating', 'im drinking']
for item in a:
         if item in book:
             print('something once')#just one item found to Be satisfied then break the code
             break
         else:
             print('the opposite somthing once')#if the two-items not found print one sentence exprime this once
```

Comment: Your code actually works fine for your purposes. There's nothing shameful in using a good old fashioned for loop. Just make sure to indent properly.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your *question*?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It's not clear what you want, since you failed to provide current and desired outputs.

Comment: the question is simple: how can i make a decision like printing sentences based on two-item together?, found once from the list just enough, don't found them here the opposite

Comment: sorry for the first bad writing, im new here, just follow the edited one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` instead of the loop:

```
if any(item in book for item in a):
    #found
else:
    #not found
```

Or you can use `re`:

```
import re

if re.search('|'.join(a), book):
    #found
else:
    #not found
```

These will return True if it finds any word in `a` inside `book`. In regular expressions the `|` symbol means or.

Comment: it just an example it not a book, just like a long string the problem is the decision based on the two item together, if thes found or not, think you

Comment: See  my edit @AbdelhakBoumezrag

Comment: its a new syntax for me 
think you sir you safed my life .hhhh  :)